# Angular autocomplete loading from api reactivity

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, autocomplete

i did all the tutorials on Angular Autocomplete from API to be able to reproduce the steps. valuechanges to listen to the form control, fired the switchmap to resend the request every new keywords, then load the data to the autocomplete. It's working but after loading the last request from service, i need to do an action (clocking or typing) to see the last result from response on the autocomplete dropdown. I tested it on a new Angular project and i don't have this problem. My version of Angular is 10.

The code to load the data :

```
// Search a place
  search = new FormControl();
  body: any;
  isLoading: boolean;
  errorMsg: string;
  filteredPlace: any;
  places = [];
  minLengthTerm = 2;
  selectedValue = '';
  @ViewChild(MatAutocompleteTrigger) autocomplete: MatAutocompleteTrigger;    

this.search!.valueChanges.pipe(
          distinctUntilChanged(),
          debounceTime(500),
          tap(() => { 
            this.places = [];
          }),
          filter(value => value? true: false),
          switchMap(search => 
            this.placeService.searchPlace(search).pipe(catchError(() => of([]))))
            )
            .subscribe((val) => {
              this.places = val;
              console.log(val);
              if (this.places.length === 0) {
                // If no result we show the possibility to create a place
                console.log(('No Data'));
                this.autocomplete.closePanel();
              }
            })
onSelResult(option: any){
    this.selectedValue = option.name;
    console.log(option);
  }

  clearSelection() {
      this.selectedValue = '';
      this.places = [];
  }
```

The html :

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Rechercher un lieu</mat-label>
    <input 
      matInput
      placeholder="Type de lieu, nom, adresse, département, code postal, ville" 
      [formControl]="search"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
      [value]="selectedValue">
      <button
        matSuffix mat-icon-button  
        aria-label="Clear" (click)="clearSelection()">
        <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let place of places" (onSelectionChange)="onSelResult(place)">
          <span><b>{{place.name}}</b> ({{place.zipCode}})</span>
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
    <mat-hint>
      Vous pouvez séparer par des virgules pour lancer la recherche sur plusieurs champs. <b>Exemple : Cimetière, 95</b>
    </mat-hint>
  </mat-form-field>
```

I dont know why i need to do an action to see the last result of my request (array of objects) in the autocomplete dropdown.

I tried to load the data in an Observable before to load autocomplete, and use the async pipe in the html, but of course with this solution the data is not changing on valuechanges. And even if i update the observable with this method (after switchmap) i have the same issue.

Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

If finally find this example with a filter on the results and it work much well.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wazyiq-vhvssz?file=app%2Fautocomplete-simple-example.html